# Why is this bool value not saving?

Tags: swift3

I am trying to save a simple piece of information using NSUserdefaults. I am trying to save a SKSprite to have an alpha of 1 using a bool value. Here is how I am doing it.

First scene: Level select (sprite alpha is 0.2)
When user completes Level: (edit sprite in Level Select to equal one)

GameViewController:

```
//
//  GameViewController.swift
//  Maze
//
//  Created by PixelatedAngel on 4/24/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 PixelatedAngel. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

public let levelselect = SKScene(fileNamed: "LevelSelect")

class GameViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
        // Load the SKScene from 'GameScene.sks'
        if let scene = levelselect {
            // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
            scene.scaleMode = .fill
            // Present the scene
            view.presentScene(scene)
        }
        view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
        view.showsFPS = true
        view.showsNodeCount = true
    }
}

override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone {
        return .allButUpsideDown
    } else {
        return .all
    }
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    //saved data here
    if let x = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "LevelOne")
    {
        isLevelOneCompleted = x as! Bool
    }

    if let z = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "LevelTwoButton")
    {
        unlockLevelTwoButton = z as! Bool
        print("Trying to Retrive the value of Level Two Button")
    }
}
}
```

Level One:

```
//
//  GameScene.swift
//  Maze
//
//  Created by PixelatedAngel on 4/24/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 PixelatedAngel. All rights reserved.
//

import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit
import CoreMotion

public var isLevelOneCompleted = false
public var unlockLevelTwoButton = false

class LevelOne: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
    var levelonescene:SKScene!
    var player = SKSpriteNode()
    var endNode = SKSpriteNode()
    let manager = CMMotionManager()

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody (edgeLoopFrom: self.frame)
    self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self

    player = self.childNode(withName: "player") as! SKSpriteNode
    player.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = 1
    endNode = self.childNode(withName: "endNode") as! SKSpriteNode
    endNode.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = 2
    manager.startAccelerometerUpdates()
    manager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = 0.1
    manager.startAccelerometerUpdates(to: OperationQueue.main){
        (data, error) in

        self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: ((data?.acceleration.x)! * 10), dy: ((data?.acceleration.y)! * 10))
    }
}

func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    var bodyA = contact.bodyA
    var bodyB = contact.bodyB
    let threeStars = SKScene(fileNamed: "LevelCompleted3Star")

    let fadeAction = SKAction.fadeAlpha(by: 1, duration: 0.45)

    if bodyA.categoryBitMask == 1 && bodyB.categoryBitMask == 2 || bodyA.categoryBitMask == 2 && bodyB.categoryBitMask == 1{
        print("Level One complete")
        levelOneCompleted()
        unlockLevelTwo()
        //3 stars
        threeStars?.scaleMode = .fill
        self.view?.presentScene(threeStars!, transition: .fade(withDuration: 0.3))
 }
        }

func levelOneCompleted(){
    isLevelOneCompleted = true
}

func unlockLevelTwo(){
    unlockLevelTwoButton = true
    print("unlock level two = true")
}        
}
```

3 Star:

```
//
//  GameScene.swift
//  Maze
//
//  Created by PixelatedAngel on 4/24/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 PixelatedAngel. All rights reserved.
//

import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit
import CoreMotion

public let levelselectscene = SKScene(fileNamed: "LevelSelect")

class LevelCompletedThreeStar: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if isLevelOneCompleted == true{
            print("islevelonecompleted is true..")
            UserDefaults.standard.set(isLevelOneCompleted, forKey: "LevelOne")
            UserDefaults.standard.set(unlockLevelTwoButton, forKey: "LevelTwoButton")
            UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
            levelselect?.scaleMode = .fill
            levelselect?.childNode(withName: "levelTwoButton")?.alpha = 1
            self.view?.presentScene(levelselect)
        }
}
}
```

Level Select:

```
//
//  GameScene.swift
//  Maze
//
//  Created by PixelatedAngel on 4/24/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 PixelatedAngel. All rights reserved.
//

import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class LevelSelect: SKScene {

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

        if let z = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "LevelTwoButton")
        {
            unlockLevelTwoButton = z as! Bool
            print("Trying to Retrive the value of Level Two Button in Level Select")
        }

        if unlockLevelTwoButton == true {
            levelselectscene?.childNode(withName: "LevelTwoButton")?.alpha = 1
               UserDefaults.standard.set(unlockLevelTwoButton, forKey: "LevelTwoUnlocked")
            print("I got this far")
        }
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        let levelOne = SKScene(fileNamed: "LevelOne")
        levelOne?.scaleMode = .fill

        let levelTwo = SKScene(fileNamed: "LevelTwo")
        levelTwo?.scaleMode = .fill

        for touch in touches {
            let location = touch.location(in: self)
            let node : SKNode = self.atPoint(location)
            if node.name == "levelOneButton" {
                self.view?.presentScene(levelOne!, transition: SKTransition.fade(withDuration: 0.2))
                }

            if isLevelOneCompleted == true && node.name == "levelTwoButton"{
                self.view?.presentScene(levelTwo!, transition: SKTransition.fade(withDuration: 0.2))

            }
        }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you add a print statement in touchesBegan, the block where isLevelOneCompleted is true,  and the block where you retrieve the value as z - confirm all 3 are called as you expect.

Comment: Just to point it out, you use both "levelTwoButton" and  "LevelTwoButton"

Comment: I have just done what you have suggested. Everything works great when inside the app running the first time. Every print works when the Bool is changed. When the app is closed and re-opened the key is not being read and the print is not being shown.

Comment: The key is being retrieved in the app the first time too though. It prints just fine then. But when you close the app and re-open the key is not being read.

Comment: Could it be that i'm not calling the same instance of the scene when going back into the app? I'm not sure how i would do that though.

Comment: Can you think of any code you haven't shown which might be involved? I feel like we're missing something that's obvious. I guess it will be once you've found it. It's way too early to give up.

Comment: try this:        if let z = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "LevelTwoButton") Unfortunately this doesn't address the issue of it no longer working when you re-open the app.

Comment: I have tried this and did not work. I have also tried a print for my other key "LevelOne". It doesn't look like it is retrieving that key either. It looks as if it is not going to the Gameviewcontroller when the app is re-opened in my opinion

Comment: can you retrieve everything at app startup?  write a method in AppDelegate.swift and call it from application didLaunchWithOptions

Comment: Looks like it doesn't get there at all. I have set a print and doesn't even get it called. Also, everything works on first start up of app. Just not second time.

Comment: Jesus Christ, please work on your use of empty lines.

Comment: @MattCantrelle Please don't delete vital parts of your question. Once you've posted to the site, it's unfair to delete your question, because future readers cannot learn anything if you delete your code. Regardless, the revision history for your post is **public**, and even editing the code away will not delete it. Consider narrowing down your code to a [mcve] in future if you don't want to publish large amounts of code (this is good practice anyway for the site).

Comment: @Aurora0001 Yes sir, sorry about that. Won't happen again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your view controller, GameViewController, you get the value you have stored.  Later in the app lifecycle, you instantiate your game scene: LevelOne.  When LevelOne is initialized, you set your global variable to false [without checking user defaults]. I wonder if it would make a difference if, instead of declaring your global in a different file, you define it at the top of your view controller, and set it in viewDidLoad after checking user defaults.  You could even make the global variable static.

Comment: I actually made something like this last night and it saved the value. :))

Comment: Excellent! Congrats.